# Error installing software and environment variables

Tags: java, windows, installation

I want to install a software using the following command in my command prompt:

`java -Xmx256m -Xms64m -jar TreeForm.jar`

However what I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.misc.Launcher
        at userInterface.Start.<clinit>(Start.java:54)Exception in thread "main"
```

And if I define an environment variable as `_JAVA_OPTIONS` = `-Xmx256m -Xms64m`, with an additional line on top:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx256m -Xms64m
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.misc.Launcher
        at userInterface.Start.<clinit>(Start.java:54)
```

How can I solve this? I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the java version you are running. If my memory is correct then `sun.misc.*` has been removed starting java 9.
Please check you are using your java version with the command.

`java -version`

Comment: This is the output of the command: `Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx256m -Xms64m
java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)`

Comment: Your java version is 17. To use `sun.misc.*` use java 8.
`sun.misc.*` removed starting from java 9